# How can I code Wordpress page in Drop Down List?

Tags: wordpress

How can I do code the wordpress page into dropdown list something like this
 
    Page 1
    Page 2
    Page 3

and then when I click submit it goes to the selected page.. .thank you so much guys in advance.. .

-idontknowhow

Comment: This would be better asked on the WordPress SE site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [get_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) to fech all the pages under the system, there's an example to do exactly what you want:

```
<select name="page-dropdown"
    onchange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'> 
    <option value=""><?php echo attribute_escape(__('Select page')); ?></option> 
    <?php 
        $pages = get_pages(); 
        foreach ($pages as $pagg) {
            $option = '<option value="'.get_page_link($pagg->ID).'">';
            $option .= $pagg->post_title;
            $option .= '</option>';
            echo $option;
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Adirael thanks for fast respond should I put a 
<form action="page"></form>  to goes to selected page? sorry for my question I'm  new in wordpress... thank you so much.. .

Comment: Is not really necessary, this doesn't has a Go or Submit button, the second line reads: "onchange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'" so it will automatically redirect the user to the selected page on the dropdown.